# Resteasy: How does json extension get extracted from /customers.json

Tags: resteasy

I don't understand how the below class is able to recognize the request /customers.json as the /customers path and able to extract and extract the json extension.  There is no path parameters.

"Consider this

```
 JAX-RS resource class:
 @Path("/customers")
 public class CustomerResource 
 {
    @GET
    @Produces("application/xml")
    public Customer getXml() {...}
    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Customer getJson() {...}
 }
```

For this CustomerService JAX-RS resource class, if a request of GET /custom
ers.json came in, the JAX-RS implementation would extract the .json suffix and remove
it from the request path. It would then look in its media type mappings for a media
type that matched json. In this case, let’s say json mapped to application/json. It
would use this information instead of the Accept header and dispatch this request to
the getJson() method."

Answer (score 0):

I got the official answer from author: "The specification does not define a facility for this, but most JAX-RS implementations support it."